# How to unpack binary formatted dates in python?

Tags: python, python-2.6, pack, unpack

In a database export file i have a column with dates which are stored in binary format.
I'm trying to unpack dates in the file so that "\x07\xdb\x0c\x01" becomes "01-12-2011" again.

I know how the hexadecimal values corresspond to their decimal counterpart,

```
0x07DB = 2011
0x0C = 12
0x01 = 01
```

But how to properly unpack these formatted dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to unpack these values to a tuple of integers:

```
import struct
year, month, day = struct.unpack('>HBB', "\x07\xdb\x0c\x01")
```

The `>HBB` format specifier tells `struct` to expect 3 values in little endian format, one unsigned short (a 2 byte value, read as an integer) and to unsigned chars (1 byte values, read as integers).

You could then pass these to `datetime.date()` to create a date object if you want:

```
from datetime import date
import struct

somedate = date(*struct.unpack('>HBB', "\x07\xdb\x0c\x01"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import struct
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date(*struct.unpack('>HBB', "\x07\xdb\x0c\x01"))
datetime.date(2011, 12, 1)
```

or you could use string formatting:

```
>>> '{2:02d}-{1:02d}-{0}'.format(*struct.unpack('>HBB', "\x07\xdb\x0c\x01"))
'01-12-2011'
```

to create a string representing that date.